# Bluetooth Android - adobe Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

i'm developing an app that needs to connect to an embedded system (Pic18fXXXX) via bluetooth
i used the ANE lib. described here.
http://as3breeze.com/bluetooth-ane/

all fine, datatypes and methods imported as default, but when compiling into android application (testing or publishing) i get :

> The content cannot be loaded because there was a problem loading an extension: Error: Extension namespace is invalid for C:\Users\Mhood\AppData\Local\Temp\Tmp_ANE_File_Unzipped_Packages\AndroidBluetooth.ane

Comment: Could you add the AIR SDK version you are using to your question, the operating system?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a version mismatch between the AIR SDK you are using and the one required for the native library. Here is the content of the extension descriptor for the Bluetooth ANE extension:

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.4">
  <id>com.as3breeze.air.ane</id>
  <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
  <platforms>
    <platform name="Android-ARM">
      <applicationDeployment>
        <nativeLibrary>AndroidBluetooth.jar</nativeLibrary>
        <initializer>com.as3breeze.air.BluetoothExtension</initializer>
        <finalizer>com.as3breeze.air.BluetoothExtension</finalizer>
      </applicationDeployment>
    </platform>
  </platforms>
</extension>
```

From the Adobe docs:

> The namespace is one of the factors, along with the SWF version, that
>   determines compatibility between an AIR SDK and an ANE file. The AIR
>   application must be packaged with a version of the AIR SDK that equals
>   or exceeds the extension namespace. Thus an AIR 3 application can use
>   an extension with the 2.5 namespace, but not the 3.1 namespace.

Did you use the required Adobe AIR 3.4 version? Check the Adobe documentation of [Native Extension descriptor files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS901d38e593cd1bac-3004221412afa24c001-8000.html) for more details.